# Install nvim-tree.lua init.vim or init.lua?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I'm totally new to neovim. I already snap-installed neovim (Ubuntu) and I want now to install [nvim-tree](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua).

[The documentation](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua) confuses me.

Here is my file `.config/nvim/init.vim`

```
call plug#begin(has('nvim') ? stdpath('data') . '/plugged' : '~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua'
call plug#end()
```

Now calling `:PlugInstall` in neovim seems to install something.

But in the "Setup" part of the doc, it is said to add this in `init.lua`:

```
vim.g.loaded_netrw = 1
vim.g.loaded_netrwPlugin = 1
vim.opt.termguicolors = true
require("nvim-tree").setup()
```

Since `init.vim` and `init.lua` are exclusive, I do not know what to do.

If I remove `init.vim` and create the file `init.lua`, I get this error:

```
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/laurent/.config/nvim/init.lua:4: module 'nvim-tree' not foun
d:
        no field package.preload['nvim-tree']
        no file './nvim-tree.lua'
        no file '/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/nvim-tree.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nvim-tree.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nvim-tree/init.lua'
        no file '/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/share/lua/5.1/nvim-tree.lua'
        no file '/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/share/lua/5.1/nvim-tree/init.lua'
        no file './nvim-tree.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/nvim-tree.so'
        no file '/build/nvim/parts/nvim/build/.deps/usr/lib/lua/5.1/nvim-tree.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/laurent/.config/nvim/init.lua:4: in main chunk
```

QUESTIONS:

- Do I have to stick with `init.vim` or `init.lua` (or is it a choice with no consequences ?)
- How do I install/use the plugin nvim-tree ?

Answer (score 3):

Answer to myself. It turns out that this works:

In  `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
call plug#begin(has('nvim') ? stdpath('data') . '/plugged' : '~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua'
call plug#end()

lua << EOF
vim.g.loaded_netrw = 1
vim.g.loaded_netrwPlugin = 1
vim.opt.termguicolors = true
require("nvim-tree").setup()
EOF
```

Then in neovim: `:PlugInstall`.

But I'm far from being sure that this is a good solution.

Comment: as in the doc, it can also be installed with *packer*. then you only need `init.lua`.

Comment: I have similar problem. My question is: did you give up `init.vim`? Because I have more configurations there and if possible, I would prefer to not move to Lua yet.

Comment: @VictorHMartin I continued like that with `init.vim`. When I need to add lua code, I put it in `lua << EOF ... EOF` and it works. As an example, I recently added ~30 lines of lua to configure [indent-blankline](https://github.com/lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim) and it works perfectly well.

Comment: @LaurentClaessens I've faced the same issue on my machine `ubuntu 22.04`, when I had my file named `init.lua`, but when I changed to `init.vim` it worked fine. I completely gave up on `nvim-tree` cuz it requires `.lua`, and switched to `preservim/nerdtree`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue and found the following to be a cleaner solution:

- rename my `init.lua` file to something else (I used `myinit.lua`)
- add `source ~/.config/nvim/myinit.lua` to the end of my `init.vim` file (alternatively you can use `luafile` instead of `source`)

This way I can keep all the lua code contained to it's own file and don't have to use that ugly `lua << EOF ... EOF` syntax, but it's functionally equivalent anyway